# Navbar with Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I can't seem to find the problem why my Navbar is not stretching to full width. for some unknown reason the corners are rounded and not straight.
I also have a problem with the way the bottom Navbar looks on the iphone.
What can I do to make it adjust to the small width and still look good?

[Here is my code:](http://bootply.com/104721)

Thank you,
Keren.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://bootply.com/104762#

changed

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-static" role="navigation">

<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="navbar-header">
     <a href="#" class="navbar-brand navbar-left">PRECISE</a>
</div>
<button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button>
```

to

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" role="navigation">

<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="navbar-header">
    <a href="#" class="navbar-brand navbar-left">PRECISE</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">
       <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
</div>
```

Not clear about what you want to do with your footer. Maybe you want to read through the [Bootstrap3 official guides](http://getbootstrap.com/components/).